# makeKeyWindowAndVisible not working

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I create a new UIWindow and want to show a view in the window like popover view, but It do not show up.(The code I read SVProgressHUD for reference)

the code is below:

In .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PopoverView : UIWindow

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;

- (void)show;

@end
```

In .m file

```
@interface PopoverView () 

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIWindow *prevKeyWindow;

@end


@implementation PopoverView

@synthesize items=_items;
@synthesize prevKeyWindow;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    if (self) {
        self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
        // Initialization code
        UILabel *view = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self addSubview:view];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)show {
    if (![self isKeyWindow]) {
        self.prevKeyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        [self makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}

@end
```

Anyone help?

Comment: - (void)show {
    if (![self isKeyWindow]) {
        self.prevKeyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        [self makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
} You have to give this code in app delegate file..I mean where u initialize your window.

Comment: Now you are trying to show a window AS look like pop over.It will not work.I didnt try it.anyway all the best

Comment: Here is the code for initialize:
`PopoverView *pop = [[PopoverView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 80, 80)];
    [pop show];`

Answer (score 0):

The PopoverView variable must be a global variable, if it's a local variable, the UIWindow will be destroyed, so you can't see it(appeared and disappeared very quickly).